# NumPy - Faster way to implement threshold value ceiling

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

I'm writing a script to modify the luminance of a RGB image using NumPy and CV2 via converting from RGB to YCrCb and back again.  However, the loop I'm using takes a while to execute, and am wondering if there is a faster way.

```
import cv2 as cv, numpy as np

threshold = 64
image = cv.imread("motorist.jpg", -1)
image.shape # Evaluates to (1000, 1500, 3)

im = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_RGB2YCR_CB)

for row in image:
    for col in row:
        if col[0] > threshold:
            col[0] = threshold

image = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_YCR_CB2RGB)
cv.imwrite("motorist_filtered.jpg", image)
```

That nested loop implementing the threshold comparison takes at least 5-7 seconds to execute.  Is there a faster method to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The idea is to create a [*mask*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html) that lets you use the numpy's vectorization. Since the shape is `(n,m,3)`, loop over the first two dimensions and grab the first index of the last dimension with `[:,:,0]`

```
idx = image[:,:,0] > threshold
image[idx,0] = threshold
```

Comment: @Jason It's worth running this and printing out what `idx` looks like. It's a giant array of size `(n,m)` filled with True/False. Indexing a numpy array with a mask _only_ grabs those values that are True in the mask. Broadcasting and masking are _the_ ways to get your numpy code running up to speed.

Comment: when I ran your example, it did execute much faster.  However, the predominant effect was much more green in the image, as if the luminance channel was green instead.

Comment: Nevermind my last comment.  It was due to converting back to RGB and saving to file.  If I write the YCrCb image to file, the effect looks the way it should.

Comment: @Jason Are you sure you are using the variables `im` and `image` correctly in the code above? I noticed something strange when looking at your example, the loop modifies `image` but you use `im` when applying `cv.cvtColor`. Since the question is about vectorizing the numpy loop I ignored the other portions.

Comment: This code seems to modify all channels, instead of just channel 0 though.

Comment: @seberg You're correct - it's been updated to only change channel 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `clip`:

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html

Usage:

```
result = im.copy()
result[..., 0] = np.clip(im[..., 0], 0, threshold)
```

Or to modify in-place:

```
np.clip(im[..., 0], 0, threshold, out=im[..., 0])
```

Comment: That clips all values of the pixels, not just the single luminance channel of which I am targeting

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

image[..., 0] = np.minimum(image[..., 0], threshold)
```

Edit: Sorry, I can't add comments yet. I was feeling lazy yesterday. True about the in place modification but it is rather obvious or you don't need it. And laziness was a response to a lazy question - there is a function for 'everything' in numpy - just check the docs.

Comment: Can you add some explanation with this? Answers with no explanation are frowned on.

Comment: @Keith Pinson, agreed, one could even consider it as lazy ;)